# How to trim special characters from start & end of the html input using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textbox in html where I want to remove all the special characters at the start & end of the string, there are lots of answers to remove the string at index 0/str.length or using string.replace or regex. But if there is no answer about how to get rid of all the special characters in the start & end of the textbox data. I have the character range as .,:'-_ / that cannot be at the start or end of input.

In jquery, I have a blur event which will do the task of trimming out the chars in the range

Eg pseudo code:

```
$( "#txtbox1" ).blur(function(){ 
    var regex = "(\.\,\:\'\\\-\_\/)+";
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(regex,""));
});
```

But somehow I am not able to understand how to specify that the replace is suppose to be only at start & end not in the middle. As the textbox can have two sentences. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Passing something like *"regex starts with and ends with"* to your favorite search engine very likely will display you [*Anchors: string start ^ and end $*](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors) amongst the first listed results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex below to achieve your result:

```
^[-.,:'_/]+|[-.,:'_/]+$
```

**Explanation of the above Regex:**

> **`^`** - Represents the start of the test String.
>
> **`|`** - Represents alternation.
>
> **`$`** - Represents end of the given test string.
>
> **`[-.,:'_/]+`** - Start or end of the string contains **one or more** of the characters mentioned.

Demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/7pWC8U/8)

**Implementation in JAVASCRIPT(JQUERY). You can modify the code accordingly.**

```js
const regex = /^[-.,:'_/]+|[-.,:'-_/]+$/gm;
const str = `bsvisbvskbvksv
nvlvnlvlv slcls
vnelvnelvnelv vnvsvnlvnl!
ocnsocnsocnosc ohoiIBIBiiwciv!
:nvkvnskvbskv
-bvksvbskvbsk sncksncks -cnscns-
--bvsjvbjvbjbvdbvkdbvkd-- vvnskvnskd --
lsvnslvnlsvnls:
Hello world
hellow WOLDF`;
//Notice in the 6th case above; only the last "-" gets replaced
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One does not need the escaping of regexp-specific characters within this character class, and as for the minus/range thingy ... placing it first or last helps also the reading. I even would force one or more leading/trailing characters ... `(/^[-_.,:'/]+|[-_.,:'/]+$/m);`

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger for the suggestion.  Updated the same

Answer (score 0):

So... I'm fairly new to regex but I've worked out something that should work for you, if not let me know:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let value = $('input[name="input"]').val();

        value = value.replace(
          /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/, // Replace first character
          ''
        );

        value = value.replace(
          /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]$/, //Replace last character
          ''
        );

        console.log(value); // => Gives you the replaced value
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="input" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added your code to snippets @Puk. It'll help people to run and see your `js` code instantly.